# Generate const strings at compile time for switch cases

Tags: c#, types, switch-statement, .net-4.5

We have in a legacy code base on .net 4.5 (important) a static class which defines many const string values of object types (means the values of `x.GetType().ToString()`) mainly for usage in switch statements.

This is especially bad because certain refactorings break all those switch statements and the places where this is used is so vast that we can't change it. I know other solutions if I would write it now, but:

Is there any way - without changes the switch statements - to define the const strings of types to pickup the compile time type since I have all information I need at compile time.

I know that switch statements are compiled at compile time into a lookup table and do not evaluate expression in cases, but is there any way to define an const value once at compile time? The only thing I can think of is to dynamically generate code before the build. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# 6 is introducing a feature to solve this exact problem, [the `nameof` expression](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#nameof-expressions).

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test(new Foo());
        Test(new Bar());
    }

    private static void Test(object x)
    {
        switch(x.GetType().ToString())
        {
            case nameof(Foo):
                Console.WriteLine("Inside Foo's code");
            break;

            case nameof(Bar):
                Console.WriteLine("Inside Bar's code");
            break;
        }
    }
}

public class Foo {}
public class Bar {}
```

[<kbd>Run Example</kbd>](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NExv1a)

the `Foo` and `Bar` referenced in the `nameof` are types, if you rename the class any automatic refactoring tools will also replace the type in the `nameof`.

EDIT: Did not catch the "do not modify the switch" part, you can use it with constant strings too.

```
const string FooName = nameof(Foo);
const string BarName = nameof(Bar);

private static void Test(object x)
{
    switch(x.GetType().ToString())
    {
        case FooName:
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Foo's code");
        break;

        case BarName:
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Bar's code");
        break;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: `nameof` does not return the full name with namespace only the type name, where `Type.ToString()` does include the namespace. So maybe this would not work.

---

If you can't use C# 6 another option is to use [T4 Text templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to dynamically build your constants for your switch statements. The only issue with this is the assembly that holds the types you are referencing can not exist in the same assembly that you are generating the code in.

The following code assumes you have a project named DataTrasferObjects in the same solution with classes named `Foo` and `Bar`

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\DataTrasferObjects\bin\Debug\DataTrasferObjects.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#
    Type fooType = typeof(DataTrasferObjects.Foo);
    Type barType = typeof(DataTrasferObjects.Bar);
#>

public static class Names
{
    public const string FooName = "<#= fooType.ToString() #>";
    public const string BarName = "<#= barType.ToString() #>";
}
```

Note, you will need to [configure your build server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx) to automatically regenerate the code on each build.

Comment: I should have added that I'm stuck on .net 4.5 right now and need a solution for that version. But I don't see anything else except of code generation, which is unnecessarily complicated. I don't see any easy solution.

Comment: Yea, I can't think of any non-code generation solution that would work for C# 5 or lower (FYI, you can use C# 6 with .NET 4.5, you only need to change your compiler by building with to the one shipped with VS2015) EDIT: If I get time and no one else has responded I might try to write up another answer showing how to do this with T4 code genration.

Comment: I added a .net version, would be good for the question if you have an example with T4

Comment: I think you still don't understand, nameof is not tied to a .net version. It is tied to the version of visual studio you used to compile. Just like how default parameters were added after .net 2.0 came out but you can use them in 2.0 if you build with VS2010 or newer.

Comment: Ok, got it. But we can't upgrade now, there is much more stuff and people involved, as always. I'm looking on a language level for a solution. Projects are not always so simple.

Comment: @Sam Updated with a T4 example.